# HTML5 iOS volumechange event not fired

Tags: javascript, html, ios5

I'm trying to capture `volumechange` event on the iPad, but it isn't being fired though other events I bind are; *Such as `play`, `pause`, `webkitbegin` and `endfullscreen`, etc.*

The `volume` value is also fixed at `1`. 
When I'm using Google Chrome on Linux, I can see the `volumechange` event, with the correct volume updated.

Apple declares that the [`volumechange`](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#samplecode/HTML5VideoEventFlow/Listings/events_js.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010085-events_js-DontLinkElementID_5) event can be used. How can I get it to work?

Comment: I am having problem with this also, have you fixed it?

Comment: no :)
but didn't touch it for a long time. sorry.

Answer (score 4):

From official [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1) documentation:

> On iOS devices, the audio level is always under the user’s physical control. The volume property is not settable in JavaScript. Reading the volume property always returns 1.

In other words, we **can't control** the volume **on iOS** in any way.